# Probability of a block error of the (N, K) Hamming code used for a binary symmetric channel.

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I found the following exercise in the "Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms" by David J.C. MacKay book.

13.4: What is the probability of block error of the $(N, K)$ Hamming code to leading order, when the code is used for a binary symmetric channel with noise density $f$?

And the answer is supplied by the author to be
$$\frac{3}{N}{N \choose 2}f^2$$

I can't really understand such answer. I suspect the underlying idea is to calculate a probability of 2 bits flipping, which would explain the binomial and $f^2$ terms. However where did $3/N$ come from?

(the probability of block error is the probability that one or more of the decoded bits in one block fail to match the corresponding source bits)

Comment: I can't understand the $\frac3N$ factor either. BTW (not relevant) it's strange that $f$ is called "noise density", it should rather be "noise level" (or crossover probability).

Comment: BTW, in case someone tries to contact the author: David J.C. MacKay, passed away on 14th April 2016.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely seems to be a typo in the book. Most practical error correction coding books cover this. As the comments pointed out we have the block error rate
$$\mathbb{P}(Block~ Error)=\binom{N}{2} f^2(1-f)^{N-2}\approx \binom{N}{2} f^2.$$ Another way of saying this is that the dominant block error event is the 2 error event (single errors are corrected, triple errors can sometimes result in wrong decoding if they result in transforming a codeword to another codeword).

Now, if there is a block error what's the most likely number of bit errors? Since the nearest codewords are the most likely spheres the errored word $c+e$ ends up in, the most likely number of bit errors is 3, the minimum distance of the Hamming code.

So, the **bit error rate** is
$$\mathbb{P}(Bit~ Error)\approx \frac{3}{N}\binom{N}{2} f^2.$$

Comment: @leonbloy please see the answer.